# odd XSLT for-each requirement

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, xslt-1.0

I have some XML that is like:

```
farms myfarm
    animals
       pigs
         name Oinker
       cats
         name Willy
farms myfarm2
    animals
       pigs
         name Cheeky
       cats
         name Fuzz
farms myfarm3
    animals
       pigs
         name Curly
       cats
          name Elvis
```

There are lots more tags under each animal.  In the general case, animals might vary from farm to farm, but in my case, they don't. All farms have the same animals. So I can get an aggregate of animals (cats and pigs) from any farm, although a more general solution would aggregate animals from all farms.

I want to generate a report that is the opposite structure, like:

```
ANIMAL pigs
myfarm  Oinker
myfarm2 Cheeky
myfarm3 Curly

ANIMAL cats
myfarm Willy
myfarm2 Fuzz
myfarm3  Elvis
```

So in the XML, FARMS contain ANIMALS, but in the report, ANIMALS contain FARMS.

I've made several attempts , but the most recent attempt was this:

```
xsl:for-each select="/farms[1]/animals"
xsl:variable name="animali" select="."

xsl:for-each select="farms"
 .
 .
td xsl select="$animali/name" /td
```

Which actually is close to a solution because, if I have 3 farms and each has 2 animals, I end up with 2 tables, of 3 rows each. Perfect!

The problem is which you probably spotted, is only Farm #1 is considered. So I end up with:

```
ANIMAL pigs
myfarm    Oinker
myfarm2   Oinker
myfarm3   Oinker

ANIMAL cats
myfarm    Willie
myfarm2   Willie
myfarm3   Willie
```

I'm thinking perhaps I need to iterate over FARMS, then over animals, then over farms again? If that makes sense?

Advice is most welcome.

Comment: I think I have a working version now, but like tires, "she ain't pretty"... I loop on ANIMALS (to get the main tables) then on farms ( to get rows) then again on ANIMALS (to filter out animals not in this table). I compare the inner animal (sounds Zen doesnt it?) with the outer. If they match , I print the row. Works, but not up to my usual standards of *elegance*... On the plus side I think it would aggregate the general case.

Comment: What version of XSLT? This is a grouping issue and grouping is usually handled differently depending on what version of XSLT you're using. Also, it would be helpful if the input in your question was updated to be XML instead of your tree representation of the XML. (The output should also be whatever it is you're really trying to achieve (HTML table maybe?).)

Comment: XSLT 1.0 - I looked into the grouping etc. Didn't look promising. I'll put in a more XML-ish flavour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using XSLT 1.0, you'll want to use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Assuming your XML is like what I've guessed below (I'll update this answer if you update the question with sample XML), the xsl:key should use the element name for children of `animals`.

**XML Input**

```
<farms>
    <farm id="myfarm">
        <animals>
            <pigs>
                <name>Oinker</name>
            </pigs>
            <cats>
                <name>Willy</name>
            </cats>     
        </animals>
    </farm>
    <farm id="myfarm2">
        <animals>
            <pigs>
                <name>Cheeky</name>
            </pigs>
            <cats>
                <name>Fuzz</name>
            </cats>     
        </animals>
    </farm>         
    <farm id="myfarm3">
        <animals>
            <pigs>
                <name>Curly</name>
            </pigs>
            <cats>
                <name>Elvis</name>
            </cats>
        </animals>
    </farm>
</farms>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="animals" match="animals/*" use="local-name()"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each 
          select="farms/farm/animals/*[count(.|key('animals',local-name())[1])=1]">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ANIMAL</th>
                <th><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <xsl:for-each select="key('animals',local-name())">
                <xsl:sort select="ancestor::farm/@id" data-type="text"/>
                <tr>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::farm/@id"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </xsl:for-each>        
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (Click "Run code snippet" to see rendered HTML)

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>ANIMAL</th>
               <th>pigs</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>myfarm</td>
               <td>Oinker</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>myfarm2</td>
               <td>Cheeky</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>myfarm3</td>
               <td>Curly</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>ANIMAL</th>
               <th>cats</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>myfarm</td>
               <td>Willy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>myfarm2</td>
               <td>Fuzz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>myfarm3</td>
               <td>Elvis</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow thanks this is very helpful. I didn't know this was even possible. I appreciate your most excellent response sir!

Comment: My XML is actually a very different case- I was just illustrating with the farm animal example. Your interpretation is perfect.  I just tried your reply and it looks perfect.  I'm not really acquainted with some of the things you're using- templates, local names, etc. But you've given me a perfect place to learn a whole lot about XSLT here. THanks again sir you've done a very good deed..

Comment: Perhaps you can describe what this statement is doing? The pipe and key and asterisk?

xsl:for-each 
          select="farms/farm/animals/*[count(.|key('animals',local-name())[1])=1]

I see some similar code in the page you reference. But its not realy explained there. Still reading - lots of take in! I'm like XSLT 101 and this is like graduate level !

BTW this is a real world problem Im working on , not a homework assisgnment. My only classes these days are blockchain.

Comment: @Spyder - What that's doing is counting the union between the current element and the first item in the key. Essentially it's just selecting the first item in the key. It could also be written like `select="farms/farm/animals/*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('animals',local-name())[1])]"`. The link to Jeni Tennison's page on muenchian grouping does a good job of explaining it.

Comment: @Spyder - Also, please consider accepting this answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Comment: I would love to accept it but I dont see any checkbox?

Comment: Daniel I think it worked- the checkmark turned green. You really know your way around here! BTW- I guess I might have mentioned this before, each animal has a unique attribute like <pigs name="pigs"> and I know those are unique. I was trying to build off that aspect thinking I could create some sort of psuedo hash or something? I'm not sure if that makes the problem any simpler? Just mentioning it. I'm reading up on keys and local names etc, lot's to learn here thanks again for your effort it was monumentous!